# The use of the word *size* here

Tags: meaning-in-context, hyphens

I read it on [engadget](http://www.engadget.com/2014/05/16/heathrow-terminal-samsung-galaxy-s-5/?ncid=rss_truncated&utm_campaign=socialmedia_fb&utm_source=socialmedia_fb&utm_medium=fb) -

> *A Samsung-sized marketing budget buys airport-sized publicity stunts, as you may well notice if you fly to or from Heathrow this month.*

It simply means...

> A small budget goes for a giant campaign ...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

> A Samsung-sized marketing budget

Since Samsung is a multinational corporate giant, I would expect this to refer to a very large budget.

> airport-sized publicity stunts

An airport is a very large facility. So I would expect this phrase to mean roughly:

> A *very large* budget buys you a *giant/huge* marketing campaign (which would include big publicity stunts).

Comment: I guess the key thing here is that _Samsung_ refers to the company, not one of their products.

Comment: @jimsug Yes that is my interpretation. Samsung also make large appliances and television sets, so I would not use the size of its products as a criteria.

Comment: Samsung spent an estimated 14 billion dollars on marketing in 2013, more than the GDP of Iceland.

Comment: At first, I thought one or the other of these was erroneous (though I wasn't sure which one). The sentence structure seems to be alluding to some kind of irony that you've missed, so I thought the sentence means to say either "A small budget goes for a giant campaign..." or, "A giant budget resorts to low-budget tactics..." However, reading the column, I think you're right; it seems to mean, "Because of their giant marketing budget, you won't believe what they just did." Maybe it's just careless journalism, or maybe the reporter means to indict Heathrow – everyone has their price.

Comment: I think this is the rare case where a sentence actually means what it says, without irony. "Huge budgets can buy huge publicity stunts. A nice example of how far that can go was just announced: Samsung is paying to have an entire airport terminal renamed temporarily, on all signs and so on at Heathrow."

Comment: Samsung has a [(in)famously huge marketing budget](http://www.businessinsider.com/chart-of-the-day-samsung-marketing-budget-2013-6), way more than Apple, Microsoft, Coca Cola, etc. Engadget probably assumes that their readers know this, so "Samsung-sized" simply means "huge".